# Laravel 4 - Find item by column

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

I was wondering if i could get a bit of help.

Is there any way to change the 'find' parameters to search in another column?

If i use

```
$test = Model::find($id)
```

This searches the ID field of a table, but what if i want to search by the token column instead.

Is there any way of doing that?

Cheers,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
$test = Model::where($column, '=', $value)->first()
```

The find method is attached to the primary key. You could maybe override it in your model, but you have other ways to achieve your goal without overriding it.